# Toolbars child node does not center

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, toolbar

I feel embarrassed to ask this, but I am having quite a bit of trouble with this and can not seem to figure out why.

Namely I am trying to center a LinearLayout inside a Toolbar, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why it is not working.

Can anyone see where I have made the error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="@color/white"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:id="@+id/toolbar">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This code results in the following:
[picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcyPG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left inset is `ToolBar's` `contentInsetStart` which has a default dimension. You can set to `0dp` with xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware that the Toolbars left inset had a default dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper view to center anything inside the toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:background="@color/white"
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar">

 <FrameLayout
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView 
        text="Something"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
 </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```